# App to detect chipset

Tags: gratis, android, diagnostics

I'm looking for an Android app that tells me on which chipset my mobile phone uses.

I would just run the app, and it would show for instance: `Exynos 5 Octa 5410`

Requirements:

- Free
- Shows chipset
- No spyware, ads OK

Comment: @Izzy? This seems like one for you ,-)

Comment: If you go to the appstore and [search for chipset](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=chipset&c=apps&hl=en) you get plenty of candidates. It looks like you have not done your homework. This site is not about 'Can you do my work for me?'

Comment: @Mawg 4mohit was faster – but yes, I also have a list of [System-Info Tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo). Due to not using any of those, I can only make an educated guess: ***[SysHard Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo)** provides hardware and software information about your device* – sounds like a perfect match. Not tried, though.

Comment: OP, 4mohit'S answer may very well be correct, but it is always worth checking Izzy's site - he is our resident Android guru (and author :-)

Answer (score 2):

[CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en) can help u with that.

> Android version of the popular CPU identification tool for PC, CPU-Z
>   is a free application that reports information about your device.
>   - SoC (System On Chip) name, architecture, clock speed for each core ;
>   - System information : device brand & model, screen resolution, RAM, storage.;
>   - Battery information : level, status, temperature, capacity ;
>   - Sensors.